# Is it acceptable to use preposition before "who"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I'm familiar with this construction below:

> preposition + which .... (1)

If I'm not mistaken,that formula is for replacing the words "where" and "when" (I don't recall the detail, I read it in a grammar book and sorry I couldn't mention the title, I forgot).

Now, coming to my question, can we use preposition before "who"? For instance, is it correct to say:

> It's important not to raise your voice on who you're speaking.

Although, I'm not sure if that "on who" has another meaning just like the construction (1) does. I made it up by the way, the sentence.

Comment: Are you just asking about "is there ever a case where we can use a preposition before *who*" or are you asking "should it be preposition + *whom* instead?"  Because there are lots of examples of "preposition + *whom*".

Comment: @stangdon I'm asking about "preposition+who"

Comment: Your version is idiomatically invalid. *It's important not to raise your voice **to whoever** you're speaking **to*** (there might still be a few pedants arguing for ***whomever*** there, but they're a dying breed! :) Generally speaking, usages like *I'll dance with who I want* would be considered awkward and/or ignorant compared to *I'll dance with **who[m]ever** I want*.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dance+with+whoever+I+want%2Cdance+with+who+I+want%2Cdance+with+whom+I+want%2Cdance+with+whomever+I+want&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdance%20with%20whoever%20I%20want%3B%2Cc0) an interesting usage chart showing that only the *first* of *I'll dance WITH **whoever I want, who I want, whomever I want, whom I want*** occurs often enough to show on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is:

> ***Who*** should be used to refer to the *subject of a sentence*.
> ***Whom*** should be used to refer to *the object of a verb* or ***preposition***.

e.g.

> - I know ***who*** your best friend is! (***He/she*** is your best friend. Not **him/her* is your best friend).
> - ***With whom*** am I speaking? (I am speaking with ***him/her***. Not I am speaking ****with he/she***) ([IELTSsite](https://ielts.idp.com/prepare/article-grammar-101-who-vs-whom))

Having said that, I cannot omit the fact that ***whom*** is considered formal, and in spoken language especially, people just say ***who***:

> ***Who*** are you going to call?

sounds fine to most ears, although the correct (considered perhaps hypercorrect by some) pronoun should be ***whom***.

Also, when the verb of the sentence is followed by a preposition, you often hear such questions as:

> ***Who*** are you working ***for***? ***Who*** is he waiting ***for***?

The formal way to ask these questions is to start with the preposition, in which case ***whom*** is strongly recommended straight after:

> ***For whom*** are you working?

So [if the preposition precedes the pronoun](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20whom%2C%20to%20who&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20whom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20who%3B%2Cc0), ***who*** does sound incorrect. If the preposition is somewhere else in the sentence, ***who*** is actually more common.

---

As for your sentence, it does not make sense. I am just guessing what you want to say, so it could be something like:

> It's important not ***to raise your voice to*** the person (whom/ who) you are speaking to.

*To raise one's voice* (***to*** someone) is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+(one%27s)+voice#:%7E:text=raise%20one%27s%20voice%20(to%20someone,shout%20at%20someone%20in%20anger).).